# Rails Vendor Assets breaks front end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, vendor

I've got an application with many external asset libraries. In order to organize my assets, I want to store these external libraries in the `vendor/assets` folder.

I was under the impression that this folder is loaded with the `app/assets` and that the references to the files in appliation.js and application.scss manifest file would work flawlessly.

```
//= require some_library
*= require some_library
```

However, after transferring the libraries from `app/assets` to `vendor/assets`, my front-end stops working properly.

Putting the files back in `app/assets` fixes the issue.

Am I wrong to think that this is should be achievable?

Are there settings to disable the vendor folder?

How could I test what's going on?

#### Example

I'm using [summernote](http://summernote.org/) to replace textareas.

This is the result with files in `app/assets`:

[image]

This is what happens when I transfer the files over to `vendor/assets`:

[image]

The JavaScript for summernote works and I can use `$(elem).summernote()`, but the result is not what I was expecting.

Comment: How it "Collapses"? Do you get 404s? Are the files loaded but empty? Errors?

Comment: I'll upload an example with images and re-word collapse to stops working properly.

Comment: If `$(elem).summernote()` works, it means that the file is actually loading? Do you have a require_tree anywhere?

Comment: Yes I use `require_tree` in application.js and application.scss, which should also load `vendor`.

Comment: If you have a `//= require_tree .` on your *./app/assets/javascripts/* it will require all Javascript files inside that folder, not in vendor. See more information on the [documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives).

This is my advice, don't use require_tree, it doesn't guarantee order and it's the source of many errors. Just require each file manually as you  need it, it will help you keep your code lean.

Comment: Okay I will try this out and post back, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that whatever file/folder you're requiring in your `application.css` in your asset path. If not, you may need to add the following to your `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets')
```

Comment: Wouldn't I be getting Sprocket::FileNotFound?